# Copying Worksheet Freezes Excel When Files Stored on Network Drives

Tags: vba, excel, citrix

I have the following piece of code that copies worksheets from one file to another:

```
Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Set wbMaster = Workbooks("UniversalQuoteProposal.xlsb")

Dim vSheetNames As Variant
vSheetNames = wsConfig.Range("SheetExportGeneralLiability")

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(vSheetNames) To UBound(vSheetNames)
    If vSheetNames(i, 2) = "X" Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vSheetNames(i, 1)).Copy Before:=wbMaster.Worksheets(1)
Next
```

This code works brilliantly on my local machine, but when I run it when files are saved on the Network the `.Copy` method freezes Excel (on the very first worksheet).

Now, the worksheet has several formulas, most with structured referencing to tables elsewhere in the file and a few more complex (but nothing too crazy) ... `SUMIF` and such. However, this works smooth and fast in my local machine.

Setting calcs to manual before the copy operation did not work. Neither did moving the worksheet (as opposed to copying it).

I suspect its because the copied sheet has to create links to the shared drive and it's hanging. I can't flatten the formulas because they will be affected by user-entry downstream.

Any clue how I can get this to work in the network drivesor things I should be looking out for?

Comment: There might be something going on with the Citrix client clipboard redirection. Are there any other oddities around copy and paste operations in that environment?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set the calculation method to 'Manual' before you run it ?

Comment: @Comintern - it's not copy | paste. It's copying (think moving, but keeping the worksheet in the original file) an entire worksheet to another file.

Comment: @CraigT - Good suggestion, however no dice :( Still hangs.

Comment: Is it because someone else has the file open, and it is waiting for the answer to the question about "open read only"?  try copying the Excel file to a local temp directory before initiating the individual sheet copy process.

Comment: @RajMore - Answer to first question is no. Second point is good thought  however this will ultimately be run on a Citrix Environment so local temp is not an option. I did try to save on Citrix Desktop, but it still hung :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because of using an `EVALUATE` formula in Named Range on the worksheet. When I removed this the worksheet copied appropriately.